# Passing argument 2 to glBindRenderbuffer makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: iphone

I am making a simple program using `OpenGL ES`, but getting a warning

> "Passing argument 2 to glBindRenderbuffer makes integer from pointer
>   without a cast"

Since i am new to OpenGL ES, i could not fix this warning. Please help me to fix it. Here is my code

```
-(void)setupRenderbuffer
{
     glGenRenderbuffers(1, colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:eaglLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer... There was a small typing error... This code should be like this...

```
-(void)setupRenderbuffer
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:eaglLayer];
}
```